# Dimension of the center of the group algebra is equal to the number of irreducible representations- Without using character theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

In a representation theory course we recently proved that the number of irreducible representations of a finite group $G$ over the complex numbers is equal to the number of conjugacy classes of $G$. The proof we saw used characters, as is standard. But I was interested in whether there exists a proof that does not use characters, and found that (apparently) $\dim_k(Z(k[G]))$ is equal to both the number of conjugacy classes of $G$ and the number of irreducible representations over the field $k$.

I've proven that it is equal to the number of conjugacy classes, but am struggling in providing a proof that it is equal to the number of irreducible representations that doesn't rely on the original result. This is my progress so far:

First we decompose $k[G]$ into the direct sum of simple unital rings like so: Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the set of isomorphism classes of simple left ideals and for each $l\in\mathcal{L}$ define $R_l=\sum_{L\in l} L$. Then $R_l$ is a unital ring and $R\cong\oplus_{l\in\mathcal{L}}R_l$. I believe that the identities of each $R_l$ give a basis for $Z(k[G])$. It is obvious that they are linearly independent and are in the center, so the issue is how to prove that they actually span the center.

If we assume that we already know the number of conjugacy classes equal the number of irreducible representations, this becomes a simple matter of counting dimensions, so I'm fairly certain that this is a basis. However I have no clue how to prove the result without using this, and any advice would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how the irreducible modules relate to this decomposition into simple algebras? Because each of these simple algebras have center of dimension $1$ (being the algebra of $m\times m$ matrices for some $m$), so it is clear that the number of such summands is the dimension of the center.

Comment: I do know how the irreducible modules relate, but can't see why they must be $m×m $ matrices. Is this using a specific theorem?

Comment: I forgot what the name of it is. It is the classification of finite dimensional simple algebras over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: I think I found it. Artin-Wedderburn theorem? This makes a lot of sense now, thanks!

Comment: Once you know Artin-Wedderburn + Maschke's theorem the result follows fairly directly from the computation of the center of a matrix ring (which itself follows from Schur's lemma).

Answer (score 3):

It is not true for arbitrary fields that the dimension of $Z(k [G])$ is the number of isoclasses of irreducible representations; the characteristic zero assumption is crucial, and it is necessary to assume the field $k$ is large enough relative to $G$ (for instance, algebraically closed; the most precise statement is that $k$ must be a splitting field for $G$).

For instance, let $p$ be a prime number, let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $p$ and let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p$. Evidently the group algebra is abelian, so its center has dimension $p$. But there is one only isoclass of irreducible $k$-linear representations: the trivial representation.

This is easy to see: supposing that $\phi:G \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$ is an irreducible representation and $g$ is a generator of $G$, the minimal polynomial of $\phi(g)$ divides $X^p-1=(X-1)^p$ and is therefore a power of $X-1$. Irreducibility now implies that the minimal polynomial is just $X-1$.

Comment: The reason this doesn't contradict Artin-Wedderburn is that the group ring is not semi-simple in characteristic $p.$ The approach outlined in the comments will work exactly when the order of the group is prime to the characteristic.

Comment: Is characteristic zero really sufficient? For example over the reals it is possible for a simple algebra to have center of dimension greater than $1$, so it is not clear to me how to make the argument work.

Comment: Of course algebraically closed is also necessary. I have edited the answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Great. I did recall it being necessary, but it has been forever since I thought about the case where it is not algebraically closed. The cyclic group of order $4$ is a good example of what happens there, as it has $3$ irreducibles over the reals, with two of the complex $1$-dimensional ones essentially "merging" into a $2$-dimensional one.

Comment: It is not necessary that $k$ is algebraically closed, but that it is a splitting field for $G$.

Comment: @JoseBrox Yes, you're right of course! I don't remember now why I wrote that, but presumably because I thought the OP wouldn't understand what I meant by *splitting field*, and because my focus here was on the way the modular case makes the given statement false, even if $k$ is a splitting field. Anyway, thanks for pointing that out, I've edited my answer slightly.